# NIghtwatch.js: Embedded iframe can not be loaded

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

I'm using NightwatchJS to test a page with an embedded iFrame. The test opens the page, waits for the iframe to be present. All test steps work so far, but the iFrame's content tells me that the browser can not render embedded iframes.

**Nightwatch Config** (*nightwatch.conf.js*)

```
"chrome" : {
    "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true,
        "nativeElements": true
    }
},
```

**Test Code**

```
.waitForElementVisible('//iframe[@id = "botframe"]')
.element('xpath', '//iframe[@id = "botframe"]', (r) => console.log(r))
.assert.containsText('//iframe[@id = "botframe"]', 'Hello')
```

**Output**

```
✔ Element <//iframe[@id = "botframe"]> was visible after 61 milliseconds.
{ sessionId: '76685e966809e760c639d589ba318693',
    status: 0,
    value: { ELEMENT: '0.5426473824985356-1' } }
✖ Testing if element <//iframe[@id = "botframe"]> contains text: "Hallo" in 1000 ms. - expected "Hallo" but got: "<br><p>Da Ihr Browser keine eingebetteten Frames anzeigen kann...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch to the frame in order to check it’s contents, like

```
.frame(‘botframe’)
```

After you have finished checking the frame and want to return to your primary html content:

```
.frame(0)
// or
.frame(null)
//or
.frame()
```

Will return you to the original frame.